# ASP.NET UserControl For Generic Editor

Tags: asp.net, architecture

I want to make a more generic editor control for ASP.NET whereby I can use the same events / common code across any editor on my site. Has anyone got any experience / insight into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking an Rich-text / HTML editor? You might want to check out some of the available options first:

- [CodePlex's Rich Text Editor](http://www.codeplex.com/rte)
- [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) (They have an ASP.NET integration pack)
- [YUI Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) (Use [YUIAsp.Net](http://www.yuiasp.net/) to integrate with ASP.NET)

These options are all (I believe) open source and a good basis to move forward. I'm sure there are others.